# Entity Framework with XML file as the data source

Tags: xml, ado.net, ado

Is there a way to somehow map an XML file to entities, so that I can use Entity Framework with XML file as the data source. XML file is very similar to a database anyway.

Comment: The best tool in .NET I’ve found for reading XML is FSharp.Data. This tutorial talks about doing just that:
http://luketopia.net/2013/10/06/xml-transformations-with-fsharp/ Here are the official docs: https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html